# dplyr mutate based on condition across many columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

I have a data frame `df` which looks something like what you see below.

```
df <- data.frame(id     = c("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno"),
                 flag_V1 = c(2, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                 V1      = c(600, 1000, 500, NA, 700),
                 flag_V2 = c(1, 1, 0, 2, 0),
                 V2      = c(400, 600, 100, 700, NA),
                 flag_V3 = c(1, 2, 1, 0, 1),
                 V3      = c(600, 300, 600, NA, 700))

> df
   id flag_V1   V1 flag_V2  V2 flag_V3  V3
1 abc       2  600       1 400       1 600
2 def       1 1000       1 600       2 300
3 ghi       1  500       0 100       1 600
4 jkl       0   NA       2 700       0  NA
5 mno       1  700       0  NA       1 700
```

Essentially, each column `V1`, `V2`, and `V3` comes with a flag variable `flag_V1`, `flag_V2`, and `flag_V3` which contain information about how the values in `V1`, `V2`, and `V3` where collected.

As you can see, whenever the flag variable reports `0`, the value in the associated column is `NA`. I want to replace these missing values with zeroes if (and only if) the flag variable reports `0`. I want something like this

```
df_modified <- df %>% mutate(V1 = ifelse(flag_V1 == 0, 0, V1))
```

for **every** column that comes with a flag variable. The actual data that I'm working with has hundreds of columns, and not all of them come with a flag variable.

Is there a simple way to perform the above operation on many columns without having to do it one by one, preferably using dplyr-like syntax and avoiding traditional loops? I want to highlight again that I don't want to change all missing values to zeroes; it is very important that this is only done when the flag variable reports `0`. Thank you!

Comment: Check dplyr's `across` function.

Comment: Reproducible, minimal example and clear question, great first question! Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `across` twice with `replace`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(replace(across(matches("^V")), across(matches("^flag")) == 0, 0))

   id flag_V1   V1 flag_V2  V2 flag_V3  V3
1 abc       2  600       1 400       1 600
2 def       1 1000       1 600       2 300
3 ghi       1  500       0   0       1 600
4 jkl       0    0       2 700       0   0
5 mno       1  700       0   0       1 700
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
df[-1][c(FALSE, TRUE)][df[-1][c(TRUE, FALSE)] == 0] <- 0
```

-output

```
> df
   id flag_V1   V1 flag_V2  V2 flag_V3  V3
1 abc       2  600       1 400       1 600
2 def       1 1000       1 600       2 300
3 ghi       1  500       0   0       1 600
4 jkl       0    0       2 700       0   0
5 mno       1  700       0   0       1 700
```